# How to make a class that has a method which will be push values without making instance of the class

Tags: javascript, class, methods, static

How can i make this catalog class and can push values to collestion property without making instance of  the class. I have been getting this below error.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
at Function.addCatalog

```
 class Catalog{
   constructor(){
     this.collection=[]
   }
    
   static addCatalog(value){
     this.collection.push(value)
   }
 }
    
 Catalog.addCatalog(4)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what language this is but shouldn't the class "Catalog" be declared static as well for this to work?

Comment: I think this was meant to be a comment, not an answer, right?

Comment: It was, but i'm fairly new here and i haven't unlocked commenting...

Comment: problem solved ;-) -- you should now be able to comment

Answer (score 1):

As janbiko already correctly pointed out, you need to make the collection static as well, otherwise it doesn't exist outside of an instance:

```js
 class Catalog{
   static collection = [];
    
   static addCatalog(value){
     this.collection.push(value)
   }
}
    
Catalog.addCatalog(4)
console.log(Catalog.collection)

// [ 4 ]
```